# iphone- conditionally calling UIRefreshControl for IOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ios6

I am trying to add UIRefreshControl for IOS 6.

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)     ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedDescending)

if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0")) {
    UIRefreshControl *refresh = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    refresh.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Pull to Refresh"];
    [refresh addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshView:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.refreshControl = refresh;
}
```

and

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"UIRefreshControl") != Nil) {
    UIRefreshControl *refresh = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    refresh.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Pull to Refresh"];
    [refresh addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshView:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.refreshControl = refresh;
}
```

but getting the error

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIRefreshControl
Referenced from: /Users/office/Library/Application Support/iPhone    Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/DD532E42-77F9-471C-AA48-7F9EAE9268C6/Verizon.app/Verizon
Expected in:   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/i PhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
```

i am using IOS 6 SDK and running on iPhone 4.3 Simulator.

When i remove the code

```
    UIRefreshControl *refresh = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    refresh.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Pull to Refresh"];
    [refresh addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshView:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.refreshControl = refresh;
```

everything works for iPhone 4.3 Simulator. Interestingly code inside

```
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0")) {  }
```

never gets called when on iPhone 4.3 Simulator, not sure why the error. Please Help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely go with the second style, i.e.:

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"UIRefreshControl") != nil) {
    ...
}
```

As for the error you are getting, you should be able to stop that by setting UIKit to "Optional" within the "Link binary with libraries" section of the project's "Build Phases" settings.

It should mark it as optional for you as it notices you're using a class that's only available in iOS 6, but looks like it's not in your case for some reason.

Comment: This will still cause dyld to choke on the unresolved symbol.

Comment: @mattjgalloway if the code refers to the nonexistent symbol anywhere, regardless of whether it is in an if or not, then dyld will not be able to resolve the symbol.

Comment: @H2CO3 marking the framework as optional means that the linker weakly links it. This causes the symbol to be marked such that dyld will not barf if it can't find it. It just says "oh well" and marks that symbol as `NULL`.

Comment: @mattjgalloway Yes, that's true (and solves the problem). However, do you finally understand what I was trying to say?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind the code doesn't get called - when the application loads, the dynamic linker needs to resolve all the symbols in the dynamic libraries the app's binary is linked to. In iOS 4.3, the `UIRefreshControl` class is not implemented, so on devices running this OS (and any OS earlier than iOS 6) the operating system itself (well, rather its UIKit framework) doesn't contain the class and the symbol corresponding to it, so the application can't even start, even if it doesn't use the code suited for iOS6-only.

You also need to know that preprocessor macros are evaluated at *compile time,* and if your target is iOS 6, the code that you conditionally compile gets compiled and the system will try to execute that regardless of what version of iOS you're *running* the program on.

The solution: instead of using conditional compilation, use reflection and self-introspection to find out if the class is available at runtime:

```
Class UIRefreshControl_Class;
if ((UIRefreshControl_Class = objc_getClass("UIRefreshControl")) != Nil) {
    // class available
    id control = [[UIRefreshControl_class alloc] init];
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: The preprocessor macro is evaluated at compile time, yes. Well, before compilation actually. In the preprocessor step. But it most certainly will *not* execute the code and compile in the if statement anyway. If that's what you're trying to say?

Comment: Basically, no, it will not try to execute the code regardless of what version of iOS you're running on. It will compile in the if statement just as it is, with the macro expanded first.

Comment: @mattjgalloway well, it depends on what kind of 'system version' that macro detects. If it's the actual system version the actual device runs, then it won't. If it's the version of the deployment target, then it will.

Comment: No no NO. It will expand the macro to yield the if statement as this: `if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"6.0" options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedDescending) { ... }`. This will *not* be evaluated by the compiler, as it simply cannot be.

Comment: @mattjgalloway the macro will be expanded by the preprocessor, no error here. I'm also right about the conditional compilation part. Of course if the macro expands to the code you just mentioned, then it won't be executed, but this still doesn't solve the problem, for the reasons I described.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you're trying to say in the 2nd paragraph. What do you mean by it's executed "regardless of what version of iOS you're running on"?

Comment: Also, it really is because it's not weakly linking UIKit. You should not have to do what you're saying. You should be able let the compiler help out and have it as a `UIRefreshControl*` rather than `id`.

Comment: @mattjgalloway It is if it's conditionally-compiled. I just said you're right in the "This will not be evaluated by the compiler" part but you're missing what I said about conditional compilation.

Comment: It's not conditionally compiled, though. That if-statement is *always* compiled.

Comment: @mattjgalloway Yes, unfortunately. I was just trying to point out a common mistake.

Comment: (Also, what do you do when weak linkage is not available? Then you don't really have any other option than using reflection.

Comment: OK, but that's not what is the problem here. Also, it's nothing to do with the preprocessor about things being conditionally compiled - e.g. `if (0) { ... }` would never be compiled in (with optimisations turned on). And this answer is certainly not right. That's all I'm saying. (Weak linkage is always available.)